# C# MVC How Do I Write An Integration Test That Makes Sure Attempting To Register A New User Redirects To The Correct Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I have been following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0 to build integration tests for my C# MVC app. This resource is very helpful.

My app redirects the first registered user to a specific page to claim the admin role for my site.

This is the Register Page:
[image]

And this is the Claim Admin Page that the first user is redirected to:
[image]

In my integration testing, this is my AuthTests.cs file (both tests succeed btw):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using AngleSharp.Html.Dom;
using Xunit;
using amaranth.Tests.Helpers;

namespace amaranth.Tests
{
    public class AuthTests : 
        IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<amaranth.Startup>>
    {
        private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<amaranth.Startup> 
            _factory;

        public AuthTests(
            CustomWebApplicationFactory<amaranth.Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

        #region snippet2
        [Fact]
        public async Task Get_SecurePageRedirectsAnUnauthenticatedUser()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient(
                new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
                {
                    AllowAutoRedirect = false
                });

            // Act
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/Profile");

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.Redirect, response.StatusCode);
            Assert.StartsWith("http://localhost/Identity/Account/Login", 
                response.Headers.Location.OriginalString);
        }
        #endregion

        #region snippet3
        [Fact]
        public async Task Get_SecurePageIsReturnedForAnAuthenticatedUser()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
                {
                    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                    {
                        services.AddAuthentication("Test")
                            .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>(
                                "Test", options => {});
                    });
                })
                .CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
                {
                    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
                });

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Test");

            //Act
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/Profile");

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        }
        #endregion
    }

    #region snippet4
    public class TestAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        public TestAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, 
            ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }

        protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Test user") };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Test");
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, "Test");

            var result = AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);

            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

It's mostly copied verbatim from https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/test/integration-tests/samples/3.x/IntegrationTestsSample/tests/RazorPagesProject.Tests/IntegrationTests/AuthTests.cs but altered for my project "amaranth."

The problem is that AuthTests.cs mostly inject a user into the database and then makes sure the authenticated view is served to the UI. But how do you actually take the test through the Register process? This is my Register.cshtml.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace amaranth.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }

        public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var returnUrl = Url.Content("~/Home/PostRegister");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

So just to reiterate, how do you actually take the test through the Register process?

Comment: I agree with Alin's suggestion. If you want to automate the registration process then you could use the Selenium web driver. With the help of it, you could create a browser object, open the URL, insert data in the web page and submit those data as an actual user do.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that AuthTests.cs mostly inject a user into the
> database and then makes sure the authenticated view is served to the
> UI. But how do you actually take the test through the Register
> process? This is my Register.cshtml.cs file:

Based on the questions, it's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

It sounds like (correct me if I misunderstood) that you're actually in need of **functional testing** and would like to input values like a user would (username, password), to then see the result of an action given a set of parameters inputted.

Functional Testing: **Look at using selenium or something similar if that is the case.**

If you are testing a registration process that is part of the application (user in your own database and all); one that does not use any third party auth system, there is no integration going on (except with the database potentially).

**Integration Testing** focuses on checking data communication amongst separate modules/apps/systems.

---

I'm posting this as an answer even tho' it should be a comment. Please clarify the intent and I will edit to provide better help. What are you tryin to achive?

Impersonate a user input and see a result?

Impersonate communication between systems (app & database)?

Anything else ?